# Deep recursion fails in grails service

Tags: java, grails, recursion, groovy

One of my grails service method is running in to deep recursion and after certain levels it fails. The most strange thing i'm seeing is there is not stackoverflowError. It only prints below

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
```

I do not get any clue just by seeing this line in the error console.I am using `grails 2.4.4.`

**Note**: There CRUD operations in the service method which is running in recursion.
I checked there is no .inputrc file in my `$HOME` folder. I am running it on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is a stack overflow, which the reloading agent doesn't like. Try running with `grails run-app -noreloading` then diagnose and fix the stack overflow.

Comment: run-app -noreloading also did not print the stacktrace. had to manually debug deep to find to cause. I do not understand why there is even need to eat up the stacktrace.